# Find the derivative of $log(sec x) $ by first principle.

Tags: derivatives

Respected everyone.

I am trying to find out if it is possible to get the derivative of $\log(\sec x)$ using the first principal. But I am getting stuck again and again. what I made is the following:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(\log\sec x) =& \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(\sec(x+h))-\log\sec x}{h}\\
=& \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(\frac{\sec (x+h)}{\sec x})}{h}
\end{align}

I have no idea after this, what should I do. Can someone please help me out ? Thank you in advance

Comment: $h \to \infty$??

Comment: opps sorry !! editing

Comment: Use $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{log(1+x)}{x} = 1$, then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$. Or you can always use LH rule.